# JavaScript to detect bottom of page does the reverse on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do infinite scrolling for a page, but the condition to test if we're at the bottom of the page is not behaving correctly on Chrome. On Chrome this alert seems to trigger at the top of the page rather than when hitting the bottom. It works correctly on IE11 though.

On Chrome $(document).height() equals 0. I have `<!DOCTYPE html>` html at the top of my page if it matters.

Oddly I took this from another example where it worked perfectly from within jsfiddle on Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/gWD66/

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
            alert("test");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your entire page ?

Comment: Unfortunately I must keep it private.

Comment: For me (in Chrome) it works perfectly, what's exactly your problem with this code?

Comment: Are your elements on your page floated left or right? Floated elements have a height of 0 unless explicitly defined. At least in chrome this is true

Comment: It's a pretty lengthy page to begin with. IE reads it as 18000px tall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function appears to provide the ultimate fail proof solution to getting the correct height of the page, at least in my case.

```
function getDocHeight() {
    var doc = document;
    return Math.max(
        Math.max(doc.body.scrollHeight, doc.documentElement.scrollHeight),
        Math.max(doc.body.offsetHeight, doc.documentElement.offsetHeight),
        Math.max(doc.body.clientHeight, doc.documentElement.clientHeight)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What kind of CSS is applied to the page, more so the body element? It could be some padding or margin that is making the $(document).height() equal something more than the combination of $(window).scrollTop() and $(window).height(). The following code will help you determine if you are ever actually meeting the if() criteria.

What version of jQuery are you using?

```js
 $(window).scroll(function() {
   var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
   var bodyHeight = $(document).height();
   $("#scrollIndex").html( scrollPosition + " / " + bodyHeight );
   if( scrollPosition == bodyHeight ) {
       $("#scrollIndex").html( "BOTTOM!" );
       $('body').height( bodyHeight + 200 + "px" );
   }
});
```

```css
body{
 height:2000px;
}
#scrollIndex{
 position:fixed;
   top:0px;
   right:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='scrollIndex'></div>
```